# Is it possible to create a multivalued polyfield in Solr that will allow custom logic at query time?

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

I'm working with a pretty niche requirement to model a relational structure within Solr and thought that a custom polyfield would be the most suitable solution to my problem. In short, each record in the index will have a number of embargo and expiry dates for when the content should be considered 'available'. These dates are grouped with another kind of categorisation (let's say by device), so for example, any given item in the index may be available for mobile users between two dates, but only available for desktop users between another two dates.

Much like the currency and the latlon types, I would index the values as a comma separated list representing each availability window, for example:

```
mobile,2013-09-23T00:00:00Z,2013-09-30T00:00:00Z
```

So, a single index record could look like

```
{
    id: "1234",
    text: ["foobarbaz"],
    availability: [
        "mobile,2013-09-23T00:00:00Z,2013-09-30T00:00:00Z",
        "pc,2013-09-22T00:00:00Z,2013-09-30T00:00:00Z"
    ]
}
```

The custom type would do the job of parsing the incoming value and storing it accordingly. Is this a viable solution? How would I approach the custom logic required at query time to filter by device and then make sure that NOW is within the provided dates?

My attempt so far has been based on the Currency field type, but now I've dialled it back to just storing the string in its un-parsed state. If I could prove that the filtering I want is even possible before using the polyfield features, then I'll know if it's worth continuing.

Does anybody else have any experience writing custom (poly)fields, or doing anything similar to what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey I got a quite similar usecase where I need to group 4 values together. You got a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Dennis, I ended up creating a custom field type and a custom filter. The documents are stored, as shown above, using a single comma delimited string, then the filter does the job of breaking down the values at query time. This filter is cached, so performance is not heavily impacted.

Comment: Mh sounds pretty good. I wonder if u can query over ranges for the 4 different values like asked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862278/solr-index-multiple-values-as-one-field

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not, considering you can write your own filter query and perform any logic you want at query time. If it helps (and you may not have to do it this way), we created a new class that extends `org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType` and overrode the `getFieldQuery` method. This makes use of a custom filter class that extends `org.apache.lucene.search.Filter`. I'll try and add a little more detail in an answer to your SO question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to filter and search on these ranges, I don't think you'll have much luck storing records like that.  It would make more sense to me to have a more structured document, something like:

```
id: "1234",
text: ["foobarbaz"],
mobileavailabilitystart: "mobile,2013-09-23T00:00:00Z",
mobileavailabilityend: "2013-09-30T00:00:00Z",
pcavailabilitystart: "2013-09-22T00:00:00Z", 
pcavailabilityend: "2013-09-30T00:00:00Z"
```

Indexing the full contents of a csv line in Lucene/Solr, in a single field, would allow you to perform full-text searches on it, but would not be a good way to support querying for a specific element of it.

Comment: Of course, I understand that keeping the value as a comma separated list wouldn't be particularly useful - it's just the way the data is initially indexed. 

The currency and latlon field types are good examples of this behaviour; at index time the values are parsed and split by comma. The LatLon type then stores the two values in dynamic fields, the Currency type stores the values in 'sub' fields, which is what makes it a polyfield.

I want similar behaviour, but I'm not sure how to have some control over how the queries work against the field.

Comment: Also, storing it in a flat format introduces other difficulties, as there may be multiple, overlapping ranges for any single device, not to mention, schema changes will be required for any new device that's introduced.