# Solr Index multiple values AS one field

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

I want to do queries on double fields where four values are actually grouped and each document can have multiple instances of this. So what I need is a field where I can store something like this

```
<doc>
   <field name="id">id</field>
   <field name="valueGroup">1 2 3 4</field>
   <field name="valueGroup">5 6 7 8</field>
</doc>
```

And then do ranged queries in this way: valueGroup: [0,0,0,0 to 3,8,8,8]. I cannot Index this as single fields with multivalued="true" because each group needs to be treated separately. I know there is a fieldtype LatLon but that has only two values. How to get fields with more than 2 dimensions?

Comment: What should the query `valueGroup: [0,0,0,0 to 3,8,8,8]` match?

Comment: [[0,1,2,3],[0,1..8]...] So the values are matched distinct in their ranges but every value has to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a response to your comment on my SO question, I also had quite niche requirements for performing some complex filtering. Eventually, I had to create a custom field class which allowed me to override the method responsible for returning a query object containing the custom logic to filter results. This method should suit you perfectly:

```
public class MyCustomFieldType extends FieldType {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void init(final IndexSchema schema, final Map<String, String> args) {
        trueProperties |= TOKENIZED;
        super.init(schema, args);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void write(final XMLWriter xmlWriter, final String name, final Fieldable fieldable)
        throws IOException
    {
        xmlWriter.writeStr(name, fieldable.stringValue());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void write(final TextResponseWriter writer, final String name, final Fieldable fieldable)
        throws  IOException
    {
        writer.writeStr(name, fieldable.stringValue(), true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public SortField getSortField(final SchemaField field, final boolean reverse) {
        return getStringSort(field, reverse);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void setAnalyzer(final Analyzer analyzer) {
        this.analyzer = analyzer;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void setQueryAnalyzer(final Analyzer queryAnalyzer) {
        this.queryAnalyzer = queryAnalyzer;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Query getFieldQuery(
        final QParser parser, final SchemaField field, final String externalVal)
    {
        // Do some parsing of the user's input (if necessary) from the query string (externalVal)
        final String parsedInput = ...

        // Instantiate your custom filter, taking note to wrap it in a caching wrapper!
        final Filter filter = new CachingWrapperFilter(
            new MyCustomFilter(field, parsedValue));

        // Return a query that runs your filter against all docs in the index
        // NOTE: depending on your needs, you may be able to do a more fine grained query here
        // instead of a MatchAllDocsQuery!!
        return new FilteredQuery(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), filter);
    }
}
```

Now you need a custom Filter...

```
public class MyCustomFilter extends Filter {
    /**
     * The field that is being filtered.
     */
    private final SchemaField field;

    /**
     *  The value to filter against.
     */
    private final String filterBy;

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param field     The field to perform filtering against.
     * @param filterBy  A value to filter by.
     */
    public ProgrammeAvailabilityFilter(
        final SchemaField field,
        final String filterBy)
    {
        this.field = field;
        this.filterBy = filterBy;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(final IndexReader reader) throws IOException {

        final FixedBitSet bitSet = new FixedBitSet(reader.maxDoc());

        // find all the docs you want to run the filter against
        final Weight weight = new IndexSearcher(reader).createNormalizedWeight(
            new SOME_QUERY_TYPE_HERE());

        final Scorer docIterator = weight.scorer(reader, true, false);

        if (docIterator == null) {
            return bitSet;
        }

        int docId;

        while ((docId = docIterator.nextDoc()) != Scorer.NO_MORE_DOCS) {

            final Document doc = reader.document(docId);

            for (final String indexFieldValue : doc.getValues(field.getName())) {
                // CUSTOM LOGIC GOES HERE

                // If your criteria are met, consider the doc a match
                bitSet.set(docId);
            }
        }

        return bitSet;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        // NEEDED FOR CACHING
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // NEEDED FOR CACHING
    }
}
```

The example above is obviously very basic, but if you use it as a template and tweak to improve performance and add your custom logic, you should get what you need. Also be sure to implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your filter, as these will be used for caching. In the query string, you can supply the `fq` param like so: `?q=some query&fq=myfield:[0,0,0,0 to 3,8,8,8].

As I mentioned, this approach worked great for me and my team, as we had quite specific requirements around the filtering of our content.

Good luck. :)